# Issue aggregate Instagram Pics and Twitter Tweets

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, twitter, nsdictionary

I am trying to aggregate Two timelines of Instagram and Twitter through this statement:

`if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)`

However for each tweet and picture it only shows every other post. As in it shows the 1st and 3rd Instagram picture, and 2nd and 4th Twitter Tweet. Here is my code in creating each cell:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)  {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

            NSDictionary *tweet = tweets[indexPath.row];

            return cell;

        }else {

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InstagramCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

            NSDictionary *entry = instaPics[indexPath.row];

            return cell;
        }

}
```

Comment: I don't think "aggravate" means what you think it means. :) Perhaps you mean "aggregate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide the `indexPath.row` by 2.

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

    NSDictionary *tweet = tweets[indexPath.row / 2];

    return cell;
} else {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InstagramCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

    NSDictionary *entry = instaPics[indexPath.row / 2];

    return cell;
}
```

Of course this assumes both arrays have the same number of objects.